# What does () => {} mean in vue props for image?

Tags: vue.js, arrow-functions

so i'm learning vue and i came across this : () => {} .
It's in props used for an image prop. What i don't understand is how would i feed information into this prop, or how would i use this?
image: {
type: Object,
default: () => {}
},

Comment: It's an empty arrow function, wherever it's used.

Answer (score 1):

See [Prop Validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation)

`image: { type: Object, default: () => {} }` defines a prop called `image` that expects an `Object`. If you (as a user of the component) do not provide value for the prop, the function assigned to `default` will be used to generated default value. In this case the function returns an `undefined` (which is same result as if there were no `default`)

> What i don't understand is how would i feed information into this prop

Well all you know from this is you need to pass an `Object`. But what shape of object is expected (what properties it must have) must be learned from the component's documentation....

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, so basically I have to enter in the object src and the value for it.

Answer (score 1):

> Object or array defaults must be returned from a factory function

```js
    // Object with a default value
    propE: {
      type: Object,
      // Object or array defaults must be returned from
      // a factory function
      default: function () {
        return { message: 'hello' }
      }
    }
```

because Object or array is reference type. If they are not generated using a function, they will all point to the same reference

sometimes we can use it as follows

```js
   propE: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }

   propF: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
```